# How can I use Bread on iOS to manage bitcoin and litecoin?

Tags: litecoin, breadwallet

I have a Bread wallet for iOS (https://bitcoin.org/en/wallets/mobile/ios/breadwallet/).

Is it possible to manage both bitcoin and litecoin with the same Bread app?

If so, how can I use the Bread app to:

- create separate wallets for bitcoin and litecoin?
- distinguish the wallets when I want to use one or the other currency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Bread doesn't support Litecoin in any way.  It only supports Bitcoin.  So you can use it to manage your Bitcoin if you wish, but you'll need to find a different app for Litecoin.

Comment: Thanks, but do you have some sources for this? I searched for litecoin wallets, which led to "loaf wallet". Looking at the github for loafwallet, it said "deprecated, please look at litecoin-foundation/loafwallet-ios". And clicking there led directly to the github fork of Bread (https://github.com/litecoin-foundation/loafwallet-ios) (note the big Bread logo). So... from that I concluded that Bread supports litecoin. If that's not the case, it's Ok, but... geez I'm confused.

Comment: @martinjakubik: I don't know how to prove a negative, but I have never seen any reference to Litecoin within the official Bread app nor its documentation.  Loaf is not Bread; it's a fork.  Someone took the Bread source code (which did not support Litecoin) and modified it to create a different app which does (but as far as I can tell the fork no longer supports Bitcoin).  It looks like they were not very careful about changing all instances of the original app's name and logo.

Comment: alright, I'll take that as an answer. Thanks. what's frustrating is that they weren't careful about updating the ... uh... link to the App Store either.

Comment: There's a reference now. From the Bread blog on March 6th: "This new version of the app sports a modular framework, built from the ground up, that enables us to add multiple digital assets to the Bread platform, of which Bitcoin Cash is only the first." So as of March 6th, they have Bitcoin and Bitcoin Cash. No Litecoin yet. (https://breadapp.com/blog/bread-adds-bitcoin-cash-ios-users/)

Answer (score 0):

The BRD wallet does not support Litecoin.  The latest IOS release (3.0.x, May 2018) has support for Bitcoin, Bitcoin Cash, Ethereum, and ERC20 tokens.